# Recursive prompt function returns null

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, prompt

I want to build a prompt function that will prompt until user inputs a value and then return that value.

Why this code returns **null** when I enter in mandatory mode and then enter a value? Can anyone make it working?

```js
function UserInput(text, defaultText, mandantory) {
  if (typeof defaultText === 'undefined')
    defaultText = '';
  if (typeof mandantory === 'undefined')
    return prompt(text, defaultText);
  else {
    var a = prompt(text, defaultText);
    if (a === '') {
      return UserInput(text, defaultText, mandantory);
    } else {
      return null;   
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button onclick="alert(UserInput('prompt with input', ''))">prompt with input</button><br/>
  <button onclick="alert(UserInput('prompt with mandantory input', '', 0))">prompt with mandantory input</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Note: it has to be called from onclick="...".

Thanks,
Dejan

Comment: Else return a instead of return null in else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's returning `null` because you are returning it in your `else` if a value is entered. In your last `else` you need to return `a` instead of `null`, when `a` is different from `''`:

```
if (a === '') {
  return UserInput(text, defaultText, mandantory);
} else {
  return a;   
}
```

**Note:**

To check if a variable is defined, you can just use `if(mandatory)` instead of writing `if(typeof mandantory === 'undefined')`.

**Demo:**

```js
function UserInput(text, defaultText, mandantory) {
  if (typeof defaultText === 'undefined')
    defaultText = '';
  if (mandantory)
    return prompt(text, defaultText);
  else {
    var a = prompt(text, defaultText);
    if (a === '') {
      return UserInput(text, defaultText, mandantory);
    } else {
      return a;   
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button onclick="alert(UserInput('prompt with input', ''))">prompt with input</button><br/>
  <button onclick="alert(UserInput('prompt with mandantory input', '', 0))">prompt with mandantory input</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns `null` because you call you do `return null` in case `a` is something else the `''`, you have to return  `a`.

```js
function UserInput(text, defaultText, mandantory) {
  if (typeof defaultText === 'undefined')
    defaultText = '';
  if (typeof mandantory === 'undefined')
    return prompt(text, defaultText);
  else {
    var a = prompt(text, defaultText);
    if (a === '') {
      return UserInput(text, defaultText, mandantory);
    } else {
      return a;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="alert(UserInput('prompt with input', ''))">prompt with input</button><br/>
  <button onclick="alert(UserInput('prompt with mandantory input', '', 0))">prompt with mandantory input</button>
</body>

</html>
```

But I would use a while do while loop instead of a recursion here:

```js
function UserInput(text, defaultText, mandantory) {
  if (typeof defaultText === 'undefined')
    defaultText = '';

  var a

  do {
    // the first prompt will always be called
    a = prompt(text, defaultText)
    // repeat the loop while  a === '' and mandantory !== 'undefined'
  } while (mandantory !== 'undefined' && a === '')

  return a;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="alert(UserInput('prompt with input', ''))">prompt with input</button><br/>
  <button onclick="alert(UserInput('prompt with mandantory input', '', 0))">prompt with mandantory input</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet:

1. if `a` is not nil, then always return `null` while it should `return a`
2. no need for `else` branch if there are `return` statements
3. You could use default parameters
4. mandantory (typo) => `n`
5. multiple branch returning the same value should be avoided

you could write a function like the following:

```js
const UserInput = async (text, defaultText = '', mandatory = false) => {
  const result = await prompt(text, defaultText);
  
  if (!result && mandatory) {
    console.log('User did not enter a correct value, try again');
    return UserInput(text, defaultText, mandatory);
  }
  
  console.log(`Returning Value: "${result}"`);
  return result;
};

document
  .getElementById('test')
  .addEventListener('click', () => UserInput('Say Something', '', true))
;
```

```html
<button id="test">Try</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```js
function UserInput(text, defaultText, mandantory) {
  if (typeof defaultText === 'undefined')
    defaultText = '';
  if (typeof mandantory === 'undefined')
    return prompt(text, defaultText);
  else {
    var a = prompt(text, defaultText);
    if (a === '') {
      return UserInput(text, defaultText, mandantory);
    } else if (a !== null) {
      return a;   
    } else {
      return null;   
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button onclick="alert(UserInput('prompt with input', ''))">prompt with input</button><br/>
  <button onclick="alert(UserInput('prompt with mandantory input', '', 0))">prompt with mandantory input</button>
 </body>
</html>
```